# How to read mp4 by frames on GPU?

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu, mp4

I need to read `mp4` frame by frame

I made such implementation on Java

```
public static void read(@NonNull final Context iC, @NonNull final String iPath)
{
    long time;

    int fileCount = 0;

    //Create a new Media Player
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(iC, Uri.parse(iPath));
    time = mp.getDuration() * 1000;

    Log.e("TAG", String.format("TIME :: %s", time));

    MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mRetriever.setDataSource(iPath);

    long a = System.nanoTime();

    //frame rate 10.03/sec, 1/10.03 = in microseconds 99700
    for (int i = 99700 ; i <= time ; i = i + 99700)
    {
        Bitmap b = mRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);

        if (b == null)
        {
            Log.e("TAG", String.format("BITMAP STATE :: %s", "null"));
        }
        else
        {
            fileCount++;
        }

        long curTime = System.nanoTime();
        Log.e("TAG", String.format("EXECUTION TIME :: %s", curTime - a));
        a = curTime;
    }

    Log.e("TAG", String.format("COUNT :: %s", fileCount));
}
```

and here execution time

```
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 267982039
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 222928769
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 289899461
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 138265423
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 127312577
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 251179654
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 133996500
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 289730345
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 132158270
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 270951461
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 116520808
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 209071269
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 149697230
  E/TAG: EXECUTION TIME :: 138347269
```

This time in nanoseconds == +/- 200 milliseconds... It is very slowly... I need around 30 milliseconds by frame.

**So, I think this method is execution on CPU, so question if there a method that executing on GPU?**

**P.S.** Android can read mp4 video in good speed(because when you see video, you see it without stab and slowing... You can see video like video), so how can I use the same methods like android use for read mp4?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It looks like currently you are getting the number of sync frames in the video.

Comment: @HB. Actually I need method that will return me frame by frame (by request) or, bunch of frames... Method that I described above is ok in case functionality, but problem is execution time... it is critical for me. I need to reduce it from 200 msec to 30 msec... There is one more my question that is similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/56791589/5709159

Comment: Mediacodec is your best option. You can have a look at the Grafica project, it has great examples - https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/MoviePlayer.java

Comment: You can also have a look at this question, it might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52036704/8199772

Comment: Also this one for importing directly for GPU use:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924645/process-every-camera-frame-as-bitmap-with-opengl

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984481/5709159